# How to first join tables and then filter rows to keep the greatest per group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to write a `SELECT` statement that *first* joins two tables and *then* filters rows, by keeping the max value per group.

## Example

The following two tables describe visitors in a zoo.

- `visitors` table includes all unique people ever visited the zoo; one row per person.
- `activity_log` table describes what each visitor did at the zoo over the course of their visit; one row per *activity*.

### Generate data (reproducible)

The following SQL code is compatible with *MySQL*:

```sql
-- visitors
CREATE TABLE visitors(
                      visitor_id       INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                      country_of_birth VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
                      );
                      
INSERT INTO visitors(visitor_id, country_of_birth) VALUES
                    (1,          'Bolivia'),
                    (2,          'UK'),
                    (3,          'UK'),
                    (4,          'Bolivia'),
                    (5,          'UK'),
                    (6,          'UK'),
                    (7,          'France'),
                    (8,          'USA'),
                    (9,          'UK'),
                    (10,         'France');

-- activity_log
CREATE TABLE activity_log(
                          visitor_id         INTEGER  NOT NULL,
                          FOREIGN KEY (visitor_id) REFERENCES visitors(visitor_id),
                          activity_time      DATETIME  NOT NULL,
                          activity_name      VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
                          what_was_purchased VARCHAR(8)
                          );
                       
INSERT INTO activity_log(visitor_id, activity_time,          activity_name,     what_was_purchased) VALUES
                        (1,          '2020-09-03 11:15:00',  'visit lions',     NULL),
                        (1,          '2020-09-03 10:30:00',  'use restroom',    NULL),
                        (1,          '2020-09-03 10:10:00',  'visit reptiles',  NULL),
                        (1,          '2020-09-03 10:45:00',  'purchase',        'coffee'),
                        (2,          '2021-02-10 15:30:00',  'visit giftshop',  NULL),
                        (2,          '2021-02-10 15:02:00',  'visit zebras',    NULL),
                        (2,          '2021-02-10 15:45:00',  'visit giraffes',  NULL),
                        (3,          '2021-07-07 13:04:00',  'visit reptiles',  NULL),
                        (3,          '2021-07-07 13:50:00',  'visit bears',     NULL),
                        (3,          '2021-07-07 13:40:00',  'purchase',        'icecream'),
                        (3,          '2021-07-07 14:12:00',  'purchase',        'coffee'),
                        (4,          '2021-08-19 11:33:00',  'visit monkeys',   NULL),
                        (4,          '2021-08-19 11:18:00',  'visit lions',     NULL),
                        (4,          '2021-08-19 11:47:00',  'use restroom',    NULL),
                        (5,          '2022-04-12 10:55:00',  'visit zebras',    NULL),
                        (5,          '2022-04-12 11:42:00',  'purchase',        'coffee'),
                        (5,          '2022-04-12 10:45:00',  'purchase',        'hotdog'),
                        (5,          '2022-04-12 11:27:00',  'purchase',        'popcorn'),
                        (6,          '2022-04-12 14:00:00',  'purchase',        'icecream'),
                        (7,          '2022-05-09 12:38:00',  'use restroom',    NULL),
                        (7,          '2022-05-09 12:52:00',  'visit reptiles',  NULL),
                        (7,          '2022-05-09 12:30:00',  'visit zebras',    NULL),
                        (8,          '2022-07-07 15:00:00',  'purchase',        'popcorn'),
                        (8,          '2022-07-07 15:10:00',  'visit birds',     NULL),
                        (9,          '2022-07-11 12:13:00',  'purchase',        'popcorn'),
                        (9,          '2022-07-11 11:23:00',  'purchase',        'coffee'),
                        (9,          '2022-07-11 11:00:00',  'visit lions',     NULL),
                        (9,          '2022-07-11 11:54:00',  'visit monkeys',   NULL),
                        (10,         '2022-08-31 9:30:00',   'use restroom',    NULL);
```

### The query I want

A table of all UK visitors who purchased something, and what that was. In case a person purchased more than one thing, show the last purchased item. Therefore, a table with 2 columns: (1) visitor_id, (2) what_was_purchased.

### Desired Output

```bash
#> +------------+--------------------+
#> | visitor_id | what_was_purchased |
#> +------------+--------------------+
#> |          3 | coffee             |
#> |          5 | coffee             |
#> |          6 | icecream           |
#> |          9 | popcorn            |
#> +------------+--------------------+#>
```

### My Attempt

I've gone thus far, and even this one doesn't seem OK:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM visitors AS v
LEFT JOIN activity_log AS al ON v.visitor_id = al.visitor_id 
      AND v.country_of_birth = 'UK' 
      AND al.visitor_id IN (
                        SELECT  visitor_id
                        FROM activity_log
                        GROUP BY visitor_id
                        HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN what_was_purchased IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)  > 0
                       );

-- +------------+------------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------------+
-- | visitor_id | country_of_birth | visitor_id | activity_time       | activity_name  | what_was_purchased |
-- +------------+------------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------------+
-- |          1 | Bolivia          |       NULL | NULL                | NULL           | NULL               |
-- |          2 | UK               |       NULL | NULL                | NULL           | NULL               |
-- |          3 | UK               |          3 | 2021-07-07 13:04:00 | visit reptiles | NULL               |
-- |          3 | UK               |          3 | 2021-07-07 13:50:00 | visit bears    | NULL               |
-- |          3 | UK               |          3 | 2021-07-07 13:40:00 | purchase       | icecream           |
-- |          3 | UK               |          3 | 2021-07-07 14:12:00 | purchase       | coffee             |
-- |          4 | Bolivia          |       NULL | NULL                | NULL           | NULL               |
-- |          5 | UK               |          5 | 2022-04-12 10:55:00 | visit zebras   | NULL               |
-- |          5 | UK               |          5 | 2022-04-12 11:42:00 | purchase       | coffee             |
-- |          5 | UK               |          5 | 2022-04-12 10:45:00 | purchase       | hotdog             |
-- |          5 | UK               |          5 | 2022-04-12 11:27:00 | purchase       | popcorn            |
-- |          6 | UK               |          6 | 2022-04-12 14:00:00 | purchase       | icecream           |
-- |          7 | France           |       NULL | NULL                | NULL           | NULL               |
-- |          8 | USA              |       NULL | NULL                | NULL           | NULL               |
-- |          9 | UK               |          9 | 2022-07-11 12:13:00 | purchase       | popcorn            |
-- |          9 | UK               |          9 | 2022-07-11 11:23:00 | purchase       | coffee             |
-- |          9 | UK               |          9 | 2022-07-11 11:00:00 | visit lions    | NULL               |
-- |          9 | UK               |          9 | 2022-07-11 11:54:00 | visit monkeys  | NULL               |
-- |         10 | France           |       NULL | NULL                | NULL           | NULL               |
-- +------------+------------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------------+
-- 19 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### Explaining my syntax

- I did

  ```sql
  LEFT JOIN activity_log AS al ON v.visitor_id = al.visitor_id 
        AND v.country_of_birth = 'UK'
  ```

  based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15077053/6105259), to already have only `UK` rows prior to the join. As you can see, this didn't work out well, as I still have the other countries with `NULL`. But I guess I can filter those with a `WHERE` clause. (However, I have no idea why it wasn't removed like in the referenced answer).
- I did

  ```sql
  AND al.visitor_id IN (
                          SELECT  visitor_id
                          FROM activity_log
                          GROUP BY visitor_id
                          HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN what_was_purchased IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)  > 0
                         );
  ```

  to filter on the people who had at least one purchase, prior to the join. Here, too, visitor with id `2` was is null and supposed to be removed.

### Now what?

For the sake of the question, let's ignore the `NULL` rows and pretend the filtering by "only `UK`" and "at least one purchase" was successful:

```sql
-- pseudo result I manually edited
-- +------------+------------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------------+
-- | visitor_id | country_of_birth | visitor_id | activity_time       | activity_name  | what_was_purchased |
-- +------------+------------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------------+
-- |          3 | UK               |          3 | 2021-07-07 13:04:00 | visit reptiles | NULL               |
-- |          3 | UK               |          3 | 2021-07-07 13:50:00 | visit bears    | NULL               |
-- |          3 | UK               |          3 | 2021-07-07 13:40:00 | purchase       | icecream           |
-- |          3 | UK               |          3 | 2021-07-07 14:12:00 | purchase       | coffee             |           |
-- |          5 | UK               |          5 | 2022-04-12 10:55:00 | visit zebras   | NULL               |
-- |          5 | UK               |          5 | 2022-04-12 11:42:00 | purchase       | coffee             |
-- |          5 | UK               |          5 | 2022-04-12 10:45:00 | purchase       | hotdog             |
-- |          5 | UK               |          5 | 2022-04-12 11:27:00 | purchase       | popcorn            |
-- |          6 | UK               |          6 | 2022-04-12 14:00:00 | purchase       | icecream           |
-- |          9 | UK               |          9 | 2022-07-11 12:13:00 | purchase       | popcorn            |
-- |          9 | UK               |          9 | 2022-07-11 11:23:00 | purchase       | coffee             |
-- |          9 | UK               |          9 | 2022-07-11 11:00:00 | visit lions    | NULL               |
-- |          9 | UK               |          9 | 2022-07-11 11:54:00 | visit monkeys  | NULL               |
-- +------------+------------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------------+
```

How can I get, per person, only the row corresponding to the last purchase (as reflected in `activity_time` column)? Please note that times within-person are jumbled. I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17038582/6105259) which seems to be exactly on the spot, but I can't figure out how to incorporate it in the existing query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical approach, assuming you are using an up-to-date version of MySql, is to use the *row_number* window function approach:

```
with l as (
    select l.visitor_id, l.what_was_purchased, 
      Row_Number() over(partition by l.visitor_id order by l.activity_time desc) rn
  from activity_log l
  join visitors v on v.visitor_id = l.visitor_id and v.country_of_birth = 'UK'
  where l.activity_name = 'purchase'
)
select visitor_id, what_was_purchased
from l
where rn = 1;
```

See [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wB4IQ0A3?hide=4)