# SQL (MariaDB) joins first then filters resulting table. How do I optimize the query?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have an IMDB database and query that returns list of titles in which both actors appeared. Here is database ER-diagram:

[image: IMDB ER-diagram image]

And the query itself:

```
select ti1.tconst
from title_principals as ti1 
join name_basics as nmb1 on ti1.nconst = nmb1.nconst 
where nmb1.primaryName = 'George Clooney'
and ti1.tconst in 
(
  select ti2.tconst
  from title_principals as ti2
  join name_basics as nmb2 on ti2.nconst = nmb2.nconst
  where nmb2.primaryName = 'Brad Pitt'
);
```

That returns tittles ids (tconst) in which both actors appeared:

| tconst |
| --- |
| 240772 |
| 326300 |
| 349903 |

The problem is that when I am joining title_basics to the title_principals, the query just takes too long to execute:

```
select ti1.tconst, tb.primaryTitle
from title_basics as tb 
join title_principals as ti1 on tb.tconst = ti1.tconst 
join name_basics as nmb1 on ti1.nconst = nmb1.nconst 
where nmb1.primaryName = 'George Clooney' 
and ti1.tconst in 
(
  select ti2.tconst
  from title_principals as ti2
  join name_basics as nmb2 on ti2.nconst = nmb2.nconst
  where nmb2.primaryName = 'Brad Pitt'
);
```

I supposed that database optimizer should`ve joined title_basics after filtering title_principals joined with name_basics (like in the first query), but it doesn't seem to work that way. Here is the execution plan for both queries:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | nmb1 | ALL | ix_name_basics_nconst | NULL | NULL | NULL | 12638077 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | ti1 | ref | ix_title_principals_tconst,ix_title_principals_nconst | ix_title_principals_nconst | 5 | imdb.nmb1.nconst | 4 |  |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | eq_ref | distinct_key | distinct_key | 4 | func | 1 |  |
| 2 | MATERIALIZED | nmb2 | ALL | ix_name_basics_nconst | NULL | NULL | NULL | 12638077 | Using where |
| 2 | MATERIALIZED | ti2 | ref | ix_title_principals_tconst,ix_title_principals_nconst | ix_title_principals_nconst | 5 | imdb.nmb2.nconst | 4 |  |

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | tb | ALL | ix_title_basics_tconst | NULL | NULL | NULL | 9595802 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | ti1 | ref | ix_title_principals_tconst,ix_title_principals_nconst | ix_title_principals_tconst | 5 | imdb.tb.tconst | 3 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | nmb1 | ref | ix_name_basics_nconst | ix_name_basics_nconst | 5 | imdb.ti1.nconst | 1 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | eq_ref | distinct_key | distinct_key | 4 | func | 1 |  |
| 2 | MATERIALIZED | nmb2 | ALL | ix_name_basics_nconst | NULL | NULL | NULL | 12638077 | Using where |
| 2 | MATERIALIZED | ti2 | ref | ix_title_principals_tconst,ix_title_principals_nconst | ix_title_principals_nconst | 5 | imdb.nmb2.nconst | 4 |  |

Here is what `show create table name_basics;` returns:

```
CREATE TABLE `name_basics` (
  `primaryProfession` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `nconst` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deathYear` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `knownForTitles` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `ns_soundex` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sn_soundex` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primaryName` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_soundex` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthYear` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `ix_name_basics_birthYear` (`birthYear`),
  KEY `ix_name_basics_sn_soundex` (`sn_soundex`),
  KEY `ix_name_basics_nconst` (`nconst`),
  KEY `ix_name_basics_s_soundex` (`s_soundex`),
  KEY `ix_name_basics_ns_soundex` (`ns_soundex`),
  KEY `ix_name_basics_deathYear` (`deathYear`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

I then made an index on `name_basics` for the `primaryName` field:

```
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------------------+------+------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table       | type   | possible_keys                                         | key                        | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra                              |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------------------+------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | nmb1        | ref    | ix_name_basics_nconst,idx1                            | idx1                       | 1027    | const            |    1 | Using index condition; Using where |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | ti1         | ref    | ix_title_principals_tconst,ix_title_principals_nconst | ix_title_principals_nconst | 5       | imdb.nmb1.nconst |    4 | Using where                        |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | tb          | ref    | ix_title_basics_tconst                                | ix_title_basics_tconst     | 5       | imdb.ti1.tconst  |    1 |                                    |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2> | eq_ref | distinct_key                                          | distinct_key               | 4       | func             |    1 |                                    |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | nmb2        | ref    | ix_name_basics_nconst,idx1                            | idx1                       | 1027    | const            |    1 | Using index condition; Using where |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | ti2         | ref    | ix_title_principals_tconst,ix_title_principals_nconst | ix_title_principals_nconst | 5       | imdb.nmb2.nconst |    4 |                                    |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------------------+------+------------------------------------+
```

How do I optimize the query?

I've tried to move filtering part to the JOIN condition (used AND instead of WHERE) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077053/filter-table-before-applying-left-join), it didn't help either.

Comment: `name_basics.primaryName ` appears to be the main key needed since `nconst` is the primary key. Its hard to say what the indexes are and a `show create table name_basics` would make the distinction clearer. Why have you chosen varchars for primary keys? INTs would be easier.

Comment: I just wanted it to be a bit more concise. I've added `show create table name_basics` result to the description of the problem, I also tried to query `name_basics` with `nconst` instead of `primaryName`, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: make an index on `name_basic` for the field `primaryName`. Then look at `explain` again.

Comment: Thanks, the question has already been answered below. I made an index on  `name_basics`, now the query first looks through `name_basics` table (added `explain` results to the description). I think I haven't described the problem right, I am not trying to optimize the query as much as possible, I just don't get why it joins  `title_basics` to `title_principles` first and only then filters through actors names. I thought database optimizer should've handled this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for movie titles, so select from `title_basics`. You want to restrict this to certain actors, so use `EXISTS` or `IN` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
select tconst, primarytitle
from title_basics as tb 
where tconst in
(
  select tp.tconst
  from title_principals tp
  where tp.nconst = (select nb.nconst from name_basics nb where nb.primaryName = 'George Clooney')
)
and tconst in
(
  select tp.tconst
  from title_principals tp
  where tp.nconst = (select nb.nconst from name_basics nb where nb.primaryName = 'Brad Pitt')
);
```

or a tad shorter:

```
select tconst, primarytitle
from title_basics as tb 
where tconst in
(
  select tp.tconst
  from title_principals tp
  where tp.nconst in 
  (
    select nb.nconst
    from name_basics nb
    where nb.primaryName in ('George Clooney', 'Brad Pitt')
  )
  group by tp.tconst
  having count(*) = 2 -- both actors
);
```

In order to find the actors quickly and get their `nconst` IDs, we can provide the index

```
create index idx1 on name_basics (primaryname, nconst);
```

In order to get from there to their movies and the related `tconst` IDs, we can provide

```
create index idx2 on title_principals (nconst, tconst);
```

For the last step, we can even provide a covering index:

```
create index idx3 on title_basics (tconst, primarytitle);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. But I still do not get why my second query joins  `title_basiscs` to `title_principles` first and only then filters through actors names, I thought database optimizer should've handled this. I wonder if this is true of any DBMS or it's just a peculiarity of MariaDB.

Comment: On MariaDB innodb indexes, the PK is at the end of the index anyway making `nconst` redundant from `idx1` and `tconst` redundant from `idx2`. On `idx3` `tconst` is the pk, but the covering index could get some gains provides the query is constrained to the `title_basic` results form this index.